# BBC: "She has planned abdominal surgery." | Does it mean: "She has undergone the surgery" OR "She has not."?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, present-perfect

This is from the BBC:

> Princess of Wales has planned abdominal surgery.

On seeing this sentence in big fonts, I thought she has made a plan about her surgery in the days to come, because I thought it is a sentence like this:

> Mary has planned a day trip to the Arctic Circle.

However, when I read the news, I understood that she actually already underwent the surgery. So I got surprised and wanted the find out where the misunderstanding comes from. In the end, it seems to me **".....have planned something..."** can have 2 meanings:

1. you made a plan about something and you haven't done it yet.
2. you have done that something which had already been planned.

Is that right?

Comment: This is not quite a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden-path_sentence, but a similar idea. Two interpretations based on "planned" as an adjective vs "has planned" as a verb. Thanks for the funny example!

Comment: 'Planned' has a specific meaning in surgery… not too difficult a meaning, but it does mean the operation was pre-determined by all parties in advance, rather than it being an emergency decision, for instance after an accident. The correct term is 'elective surgery'.

Comment: Trust the BBC to be indiscrete about such things.

Comment: Mathematicians may argue that language is missing parentheses. (She has) (planned surgery) versus (She has planned) (surgery).

Comment: Neither, ever. That phrase does not mean 'She has undergone the surgery' nor 'She has not'

'She has planned abdominal surgery' has two, very different meanings, neither seeming relevant to your Question.

One is that she has prepared for… surgery.

The other is that she is now undergoing that surgery.

Other interpretations might work and if they do, please say how!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is '[headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese)'. The actual first sentence of the article says "The Princess of Wales *has had* planned abdominal surgery." News headlines are usually written in the present tense and leave out some words.

'Planned' here is an adjective, meaning that the operation had been planned in advance and was not an emergency.

Occasionally, headlines can be so ambiguous that they make you laugh; these are sometimes called [crash blossoms](https://www.wordorigins.org/big-list-entries/crash-blossom).

Comment: If I had simply looked at the headline only, and hadn't read the text, I would have understood that "She made a plan." I wouldn't understood that "she underwent  surgery". So, I wonder if that is natural or not? I mean is it natural that I got this meaning from that sentence alone (without a context) ?

Comment: Yes - if this were a normal sentence, it would mean "The Princess has made a plan to have surgery". Native speakers are used to interpreting 'headlinese', which doesn't follow the normal rules of grammar.

Comment: Incidentally, the headline has now been edited to "Princess of Wales in hospital after abdominal surgery".

Comment: @yunus -people don't 'make a plan' to have non-cosmetic surgery.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - But their doctors may plan it for them !

Comment: @KateBunting — it’s not a matter of headlinese.  Like many past (and present) participles, _planned_ can also be used as an adjective, so ambiguous parsings (she had planned to have surgery vs. she had surgery that was planned) are inevitable.

Comment: @MichaelLorton sure they do. A surgery is oftentimes scheduled for the next day, next week, after obtaining consent etc. If it's scheduled, it's planned.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey The word you're looking for is non-elective. As in, a hip replacement is not cosmetic but it is elective.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey yes they do. It's common to make a birthing plan, for example, which for some people and for a variety of reasons might involve a C-section. For other people a C-section that is not part of the plan might suddenly become necessary during labour.

Comment: @KateBunting It could still be interpreted both ways when not in a headline, although I agree it would be  a bit unusual to use the present continuous in both ways. But you could imagine a doctor looking at his schedule for the day and saying "The princess has planned surgery today," indicating not that she made the plan, but that she's having surgery.

Comment: Since headlines are usually in the present tense (unless it's significant that it's reporting something that took place in the past), they would be more likely to say "... plans abdominal surgery".

Comment: @Barmar — yes, if you are fluent in Headline ease, you can reason that the original headline was not ambiguous, for the reasons you give, but I don’t know how many people will really say “No, headlines don’t use perfect-tense so ‘has’ is the main verb and ‘planned’ is an adjective...”

Comment: The _NY Times_ link needs a login (either a paid subscription, or a Google/Facebook/Apple login with limited access).  I'd suggest a free/open alternative, such as [this one](https://www.wordorigins.org/big-list-entries/crash-blossom).

Comment: @gidds - That's odd - it worked for me yesterday, and I'm not a subscriber.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to crash blossoms, [however](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/346777/girl-found-alive-in-france-murders-car-say-what)...

Comment: @KateBunting I tried it in two browsers (one in private mode), and it won't let me scroll below the top image without logging in.  Anyway, thanks for changing the link!

Comment: @MichaelLorton What makes it headlinese is that it omits otherwise necessary adjectives. I'd say the standard English setence version would say "The Princess of Wales had **her** planned surgery." It's the lack of the word "her" that allows for this to be a crash blossom.

Comment: Or "has had **a** planned [surgical] operation".

Answer (score 12):

The headline is ambiguous; there are two possible ways of interpreting it. We don't know with certainty which interpretation is correct, until we read the article.

The first interpretation is that the Princess **has planned** something (meaning that it hasn't happened yet), and the thing that she's planned is an **abdominal surgery**.

The second interpretation is that the Princess "**has**" something (meaning "had"—the headline uses the present tense even though it describes a past event), and the thing which she has is a **planned abdominal surgery**. According to this interpretation, the abdominal surgery is something that was previously planned, and now she has actually *had* the surgery.

So, your interpretation here is not quite right:

> In the end, it seems to me **".....have planned something..."** can have 2 meanings:
>
> 1-you made a plan about something and you haven't done it yet.
>
> 2-you have done that something which had already been planned.

Only the first meaning is possible. However, the structure of this sentence is not that the Princess "has planned something." Rather, the princess "has something," and, as it happens, the thing that she has begins with the word "planned."