# Girl found alive in France murders car, say what?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

An [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/346698/11599) introduced me to the concept of [crash blossoms](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crash_blossom). In the [linked examples](https://www.wordorigins.org/big-list-entries/crash-blossom) there is one I cannot process:

> Girl found alive in France murders car
> —BBC News, September 2012

The explanation mentions that "France murders" mean "a streak of murders in France" (I get that) and that now the meaning is clear :)

Well, not for me.

I can understand

> Girl found alive in <del>France murders</del> car

or some combinations where "France murders" gives some context (say, *"Girl found alive in car, thought to be part of France murders"*) but I cannot grok *"Girl found alive in France murders car"* which sounds to me like [*"correct horse battery staple"*](https://xkcd.com/936/)

Comment: It sounds like you've properly parsed the sentence. The girl was found alive in a car - a car linked to murders in France. Your rephrasing of "Girl found alive in car, thought to be part of France murders" is exactly correct. What's the confusion?

Comment: @NuclearHoagie: my understanding of a crash blossom is that there's ambivalence in how to parse the sentence (and that it can have several meanings because of that). To me the sentence is just dramatically incorrect.

Comment: It's not wrong, it's just that the noun phrase "France murders car" is very easily misread. It's still a grammatically correct noun phrase, and used appropriately where any other noun or noun phrase could be. The girl could be found alive in a house, in an Italian restaurant, or in the "France murders car".

Comment: Sorry, but the purpose of a headline is to tease the readers into reading the story that follows. A mysterious or punning or titillating headline does the job. That's why headlinese has its own rules aside from tight space.

Comment: By the way: the news that a headline was confusingly written is in no way "headline news." My dad was a newspaper reporter for decades and was often frustrated by the headlines that were put on his stories (or the common misconception that he wrote them as well).

Comment: @NuclearHoagie I disagree that "France murders car" is a valid noun phrase. "*French* murders car" could be, possibly, and "French murder-car" would be wildly better -- but "France murders" is not grammatical. You can't use France as an attributive noun because it already has a separate adjectival form.

Comment: As a native english speaker, I had to read the answers to understand the headine.  You're not alone, and this headline is badly written.

Comment: It's perfectly correct. France murders car is a person's name (sort of like bell hooks) and they had a successful C-section :)

Comment: @DarthPseudonym What’s a murder-car?

Comment: I'm French and I vividly remember a horrible news about murders in a car in France and a girl found alive ***many hours*** after the scene had been secured and forensics had been brought in to examine the car. If this is the story you refer to, then that car could indeed be called a "France murders car".

Comment: You perhaps know the old saying among journalists: "'Dog bites man' is not newsworthy, 'Man bites dog' is". I guess something similar holds with 'car kills girl' vs 'girl murders car'

Comment: @user3840170 It's a car in which one or more murders have taken place. The more common terms are "murder house" or "death car", but it's fully understandable. "murders car" just feels off to me, it doesn't feel like english.

Comment: @Stef The issue is not the story's accuracy, it's the fact that "France murders car" is using France as an adjective, which is ungrammatical.  It should be *French* (belonging to or associated with France).

Comment: @DarthPseudonym "France" is not an adjective, it's a noun. In this headline it's used as a noun adjunct.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym The story *does* matter, of course, since English sentences are used to convey a *meaning*, and whether or not a sentence is semantically correct is not just about whether it's "grammatically correct in a totally abstract sense but actually with a totally different meaning that the writer intended", but rather about whether it's grammatically correct *and* correctly using grammar to carry the intended meaning. If there were no murders committed in France and related to a car, then "France murders car" couldn't have the same meaning.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym I'm not aware of any rule forbidding the use of a noun adjunct when an adjective exists, but I'd be happy to discover them if you have a reference. Consider noun "spine" and adjective "spinal". We say "spinal cord" rather than "spine cord", but we most often say "spine surgery" and not "spinal surgery". So it seems that it is correct and usual to use "spine" as a noun adjunct even though adjective "spinal" exists. I would be happy if you could link to any reference regarding possibly-improper use of a noun adjunct when a corresponding adjective exists.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym There's no rule saying that nouns with an adjectival form can't be used as an attributive noun, there are many cases where this occurs. The phrasing implies that the murderers occurred in France, but suggests they were not perpetrated by or upon people from France, or that the car itself is not from France. A British spy killed by a Russian operative in Paris, for example, has died in a France murder, not a French murder.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym As some other examples, consider headlines using the phrases "Florida smuggling operation", or "West Virginia epidemic" - these represent things that merely take place in their eponymous locale, but don't really have the location as an inherent quality. It's not a "Floridian smuggling operation" or a "West Virginian epidemic".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The article [Girl in France murders car, crash blossoms](https://youarecurrent.com/2021/09/07/column-girl-in-france-murders-car-crash-blossoms/amp/) explains the meaning:

> A 2012 BBC news story confused many when it led with the headline, “Girl found alive in France murders car.” To help you understand what actually happened here, let’s look at a CNN headline about the same story: “France shootings: Girl hid under bodies in car.” What happened here is that a woman [sic] was found alive among deceased bodies inside a car that was connected to a string of murders in France.

(Note: She was only four years old, not an adult woman.)

The actual grammar here is that "France murders car" is two noun adjuncts modifying another noun ("car"). See "[China balloon](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/602859/191178)" for an example using a noun instead of the usual demonym adjective. The purpose of the plural "murders" seems to be to emphasize that there were multiple; this would seem to fall under ["a topical issue comes forth, often in newspaper stories"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/397244/191178).

Here's a similar example: [**Idaho murders house** being demolished despite objections from some family members](https://www.cbsnews.com/amp/news/university-of-idaho-murders-house-demolished/)

Comment: So the car belonged to the murderer (who did several murders)?

Comment: @WoJ It could have been owned by them or a victim, stolen, or even borrowed; you'd have to read the article to figure that out. It's merely indicating the car is associated with the murders. In the case of the "Idaho murders house" that was the place the victims were renting where they were murdered.

Comment: OK I get it now - it was a set of murders that happened in the vicinity of the car, around the same time. I thought initially that the murderer was a serial one, over a long period.

Comment: Not a woman, but a four-year-old girl.

Comment: @WoJ The headline implies that the murders occurred in France, and that the car was somehow connected to the murders. It doesn't suggest much about the timeframe of the murders (whether it was one multiple murder or a series of events), or necessarily that the car was nearby at the time of the murders. It could refer to murders that occurred in the car, or to a serial killer who merely travels from town to town in the car leaving forensic evidence behind. A "France murders car" means only that the car has some unspecified connection to murders that occurred in France.

Comment: "France-murders car" is such a bizarre bit of wording that I can hardly call this a crash blossom. It's just a nonsense headline even if you know what they were trying to say.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym: I think there's a regional difference here. I (an American) feel the same way you do, but the article in question is British, and I've seen similar compounds in other British headlines.

Comment: @WoJ also, if you would take it, another possible parsing is: "Girl, who was found alive in France, murders a car", which doesn't make sense, but syntactically still plausible.

Comment: @ruakh I think there is a good argument for setting France Murders here in e.g. italics. but preferably not quotes, which are vastly overused whenever the gutter press isn't certain or doesn't understand something.

Comment: Consider "The murder weapon was a gun." "murder weapon" means "weapon used for the murder".

Comment: The car was "associated to the murders" in the sense that all the dead bodies were in the car when the dead bodies were discovered. And the terrified girl was hiding under the dead bodies (presumably hiding from the murderer) and she stayed hidden for hours even after the car had been secured by the police. Somehow the police didn't notice her, and she was too scared to come out from under the bodies. It was truly a horrifying piece of news and I think many French people remember it.

Comment: A "murder house" is a house where a murder took place. Such places are often the subject of tourism by true crime fans.

Answer (score 2):

"The car that was associated with the murders in France". IIRC the parents were found murdered in or near their car, with their little girl still alive because she was hiding.

Comment: I understand what the sentence is supposed to mean - it is just that I do not understand how it may be a crash blossom. To me, it is just grammatically incorrect.

Comment: "A girl, who was found alive in France, murders a car" is the other possible, though unlikely, interpretation.

Comment: 'Headlinese' often isn't grammatically correct; it's a kind of 'shorthand'.

Comment: Yes, reading "murders" as a verb instead of an adjective is the obvious mistaken reading.

Comment: @KateBunting : And that it's hard to understand can be a deliberate feature: the reader is then incentivized to read the article. If the title was easy to understand, the reader might feel that all interesting information was gained and then skip reading the article. If the title is confusing, one might be more willing to read the article to know what exactly was going in.

Answer (score 1):

"France" is being used as a noun adjunct to modify "murders" to refer to a specific set of murders. Then the phrase "France murders" is itself being used as a noun adjunct to modify the word "car". The car is being identified as being in some way associated with the murders. Another example of this use is "Manson murder house": "Manson murder" refers to a murder associated with Charles Manson, and "Manson murder house" refers to the house that the murder occurred in. You could also say "D.B. Cooper hijacking airplane" to refer to the airplane that was hijacked by D.B. Cooper.